# Query regarding response of Mixpanel.track event

Tags: mixpanel

Suppose I have different cards, or section in a page with “like” button on every card. On clicking this card, a Mixpanel “like” event is fired with some custom properties – Button Name, Card/Section name etc.

Question –
Now if I want to show the count of “like” on every card, in real – time, how can we do that. An example is – if the user clicks like on a card, the count of like for the card will increment without refreshing the page. Will it be possible to get the response of “mixpanel.track” event and in response fetch the count of “like” event and display below every card.

Currently I am using below mentioned API URL which is returning list of all entries for the specified event and property.

URL – `https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/events/properties/?name=Name of property&event=Name of Event&type=general&unit=month"`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the callback in mixpanel.track
https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript-full-api-reference#mixpanel.track

One more thing you should do is use mixpanel.increment so like count gets stored in mixpanel as well
https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript-full-api-reference#mixpanel.people.increment

Hope this helps,

Che